# SoundCloud API requests 302 and 404 - Revoked Clienti ID?

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, soundcloud, http-status-code-302

I have a personal website using SoundCloud API to play my favorites tracks in the page.

It was working and i have not done any change or work but now i see that the songs can not be played anymore, i check in the network console and i see two requests, one is returning 302 redirect and the other [is returning 404 ( not found ).](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors)

**404 Not Found
You're asking for something that doesn't exist. Check the URL that you're requesting.**

See the image in attached

[image]

How can i figure this out? I do not know if it is related to my `client id` or some other Soundcloud API issues or changes.

Comment: Are you using the widget with an api key? Maybe they eventually revoked your key as they closed applications to major partners and keep revoking older keys. I also believe they made a change in their api recently.

Comment: I am not using the widget